# jQuery menu should stay opem

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu, toggle

I am running a Wordpress on twenty fifteen child theme. I found a Script to toggle menu on mouseover. I really like that feature. 
But I want to add following option:
When the user is on childpage of parent1, I want the menu to be open on this point, as it is by default in twentyfifteen. You can see it here:
[http://johannabaschke.de/impressum/](http://johannabaschke.de/impressum)

I now want that also with the script I found:

```
<script>
  var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.sub-menu').hide();
   $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function() {
   $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle(200);
     });
   });
</script>
```

It toggles menu on mousover, but when clicking child-page, the menu isnt open, like here:

http://johannabaschke.de/transeuropa-2015/

I am not good in coding, thats why I only modify WP-themes with CSS which I am good at, but Javascript is not my bet practice. Maybe someone has a simple idea to solve this?

Would be super glad and thx for your help!

54v4nn4h

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this:

```
<script>
  var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.sub-menu').hide();
   $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
   $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle(200);
     });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following code:

```
<script>
    var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sub-menu').hide();
        $('.menu-item-has-children').hover(function() {
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle(200);
        });

        //code to keep open respective menu open on page load
        $("a[href='"+window.location.href+"']").closest('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle(200);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, its now doing what I want. but there is still a problem, you can see it on the side. now when trying to select a child-page of the parent-page which is opend, the menu closes. so you cannot select a sister-page. sorry, hope i write understandable.